# revertir commit anteriores Git

Tags: git, github

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de Angular, y hice el primer build para subir la app a AWS. Sin intención, agregué los archivos que se generaron al stash y los *commiteé*, en particular uno con la siguiente ruta: `codigo.angular\cache\15.0.4\angular-webpack\9403d4f63308672893eca424e36366a5da42a828\8.pack`. Pero además, los archivos en los que había trabajado en el código propiamente dicho, no hice un push inmediatamente y seguí trabajando. Luego de eso, tengo 4 commits más con muchos avances en el código. Mi problema se presenta ahora que quiero hacer un push y me dice que el archivo mencionado anteriormente es demasiado extenso para subirlo a GitHub.

Intenté agregar esa carpeta al gitignore, eliminar el archivo, revertir los cambios y muchas otras cosas, sin mayor éxito. ¿Algún consejo?

PD: no quiero agregar este archivo a github, por tanto la solucion de Git LFS no es algo que esté analizando.

Comment: Puedes darle undo al primer commit, también puedes hacer cherry-pick de los commits que quieras a una nueva rama.

Comment: si te refieres al commit que incluyo el archivo de gran tamaño, la respuesta es no. si te refieres a commit anteriores, si, tengo mucho commit anteriores, pero luego de haber agregado este archivo de gran tamaño no pude hacer mas push, aunque quite este archivo de mi local, lo agregue a gitignore, le hice git rm, git rm --cached, git rm r, etc, nada me a resultado

Comment: desconozco totalmente lo que es undo y cherry-pick, lo revisare

Comment: Si estas usando la terminal, para crear una nueva rama ejecutas git checkout -b my_new_branch. Para pasar los commits ejecutas git cherry-pick commit-hash. Debes asegurarte que te encuentras en la rama correcta cuando estes pasando los commits. Ejemplo de un cherry-pick: git cherry-pick ff92f85cac

Comment: muchas gracias @VictoriaRamirezC buscare como se hace eso

Comment: finalmente lo resolvi clonando el repositorio de github en otra carpeta, elimine la carpeta .git de la carpeta donde tenia mi codigo local y copie la carpeta .git que tenia en la otra carpeta recien clonada. entre a la consola de git y hice git status, y vi que conserve los avances que tenbia despues de ese commit pero no tenia los commit y con ello pude hacer push

Answer (score 1):

Ok, veo que lo resolviste *a lo salvaje* :-D pero aquí va la receta, de todos modos, por si alguien enfrenta una situación parecida. Digamos que el archivo fue agregado en el commit X. Entonces:

```
git rebase-i X~ # incluyan el rabo'e cochino
# el primer commit que debe salir en la lista es X
# coloquen "edit" como la operación, en vez de pick
# guardar / salir
# el rebase se va a detener justo luego de haber aplicado el commit que queremos modificar
# borra el archivo en cuestión  con git rm
# si quieres mantenerlo en el árbol de trabajo, usa --cached
git rm --cached el-archivo
# si quieres ignorarlo, este es el momento apropiado, edita .gitignore y hazle git add
# cuando nos satisfagan los cambios:
git commit --amend
# puedes verificar que el commit tenga lo apropiado con git show y git show --name-status.
# Si hubo modificaciones del .gitignore
# los archivos que quieres ignorar ya no salen en git status
# Y si necesitas agregar mas cambios, bien puedes, solo asegurate de hacer git commit --amend antes de continuar si hacen mas cambios.
# Cuando todo se vea bien:
git rebase --continue
```

Y ya todo queda fino.

Comment: Tremendo! muchas gracias eftshift0